# Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1 in @EmbeddedKafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I want to test kafka - transaction.

```
    kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction { tx ->
        tx.sendDefault("abacaba") // Should I do .get() ??
        tx.sendDefault("abacaba")
    }
```

And I get next log when test is starting:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.

```
2023-01-27 16:18:17.831  INFO 81975 --- [quest-handler-4] kafka.server.ZkAdminManager              
: [Admin Manager on Broker 0]: Error processing create topic request 
CreatableTopic(name='__transaction_state', numPartitions=50, replicationFactor=3, 
assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='compression.type', 
value='uncompressed'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy', value='compact'), 
CreateableTopicConfig(name='min.insync.replicas', value='2'), 
CreateableTopicConfig(name='segment.bytes', value='104857600'), 
CreateableTopicConfig(name='unclean.leader.election.enable', value='false')])
```

I try settings replication factor but it don't work :(

Help me, please.

Comment: That error means that you have only one Kafka Broker when your request is for 3: https://www.educba.com/kafka-replication-factor/

Comment: How to configure kafka in the @KafkaEmbedded annotation? I try set replication-factor property but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say in your question that you deal with an `@EmbeddedKafka`. See its JavaDocs for more info:

```
/**
 * @return the number of brokers
 */
@AliasFor("value")
int count() default 1;
```

When you have a enough brokers in the cluster, then you can ask for replication factor on this or that topic, but not more than a number of brokers of course.

Comment: In the framework test cases, we add this to the `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation: `brokerProperties = { "transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1", "transaction.state.log.min.isr=1"` This allows transactions to be used with one broker.

Comment: tx.sendDefault("abacaba") // Should I do .get() ? to make sure that a record has occurred or is it guaranteed by a transaction?